# How to change the distance between the graphs on panes?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

It's some kind of histogram.
I've got MasterPane with two GraphPanes.
MasterPane layout is SingleRow. 
How can I set no gap between panes?

[Here's what I mean](http://cs407419.vk.me/v407419264/a5ad/b9uqyoJJ_pY.jpg)

```
masterPane.Margin.All = 0f;
masterPane.InnerPaneGap = 0f;
```

do not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also must do this:

```
YouLeftGraphPane.Margin.Right = 0;
YouRightGraphPane.Margin.Left= 0;
```

This work for me)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I needed `YouRightGraphPane.Margin.Left= 0;`. After that just move graph left and right